# How to append ith item from a list into another list ith item times from another list

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list `[100,200,300,400]` and another list`[2,3,1,2]`
I want the output as `[100,100,200,200,200,300,400,400]`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How is your question specific to Python 3? Please read the help text that pops up when choosing a tag for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list like below:

```
l1 = [100,200,300,400]
l2 = [2,3,1,2]

zipped_data = list(zip(l1,l2))

result = [x[0] for x in zipped_data for i in range(x[1])]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [100,200,300,400]
b = [2,3,1,2]
c=[i[0] for i in zip(a,b) for j in range(i[1])]
print(c)
```

## output

```
[100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400]
```

Answer (score 0):

the first method is:

```
a = [100,200,300,400]
b = [2,3,1,2]
c = [i*100 for i in b]
d = (a + c).sort()
```

the second method is:

```
import numpy as np
a = [100,200,300,400]
b = [2,3,1,2]
c = np.r_[np.array(a), np.array(b)*100]
d = c.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using for loops. This is the basic approach.

```
l1 = [100,200,300,400]
l2 = [2,3,1,2]
result = []
for i in range(len(l2)):
    for j in range(l2[i]):
        result.append(l1[i])
print(result)
```